# xml parsing (.length) when items at differing levels in a tree have the same name

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to get a count of messages from the xml below using javascript.

The messages in the abbreviated tree are called "item" and there are two at the highest level. There are also elements called "item" on lower levels metaDataAttributes.

> ```
>         <getMessagesReturn>
>             <messages>
>                 <item>
>                     <metaDataAttributes>
>                         <item>
>                           ...
>                         </item>
>                     </metaDataAttributes>
>                 </item>
>                 <item>
>                     <metaDataAttributes>
>                         <item>
>                           ...
>                         </item>
>                     </metaDataAttributes>
>                 </item>
>             </messages>
>         </getMessagesReturn>
> ```

The following returns 1 (because I guess there's only one messages element.

var xmlMessagesCount = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("messages").length;

I've tried var xmlMessagesCount = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("item").length;

which returns 132 (because there are two messages (items) each with 65 attributes (items)

I am trying to get it to return 2.

There are similar threads, but didn't find a clear answer.  So any advice or request for clarity would be greatly appreciated.